# Error: Invalid function provided as algorithm while using Segment_trees function in lidr in R

Tags: r, image-segmentation, lidar, lidr

I am trying to use the ForestTools::mcws() function and segment_trees in R to segment a LiDAR point cloud using a CHM raster. However, when I try to run the function with the segment_trees() function from the lidR package, I get the following error :

```
Error: Invalid function provided as algorithm.
```

Here is the code I am using:

```r
library(lidR)
library(ForestTools)
library(raster)
library(sf)

LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
las = readLAS(LASfile)
chm <- rasterize_canopy(las, 1, p2r(0.15), pkg = "raster")
vwf_fun <- function(x){x * 0.06 + 0.5}
WindowFilter <- vwf(CHM = chm, winFun = vwf_fun)
las <- segment_trees(las, ForestTools::mcws(WindowFilter, chm, minHeight = 2, format = "raster"))
```

I have checked the arguments I am passing to mcws(), and they seem to be correct. What could be causing this error, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`ForestTools::mcws` is a function from the package `ForestTools` and is not designed to be compatible with `lidR`. `lidR` cannot accept any function as input and the developers must respect some convention to make their function compatible with `lidR`.

The function return a `raster` and thus can be made compatible with `lidR`. You can make the function compatible yourself

```r
mcwatershed <- function(ttops, chm, minHeight) {
  f <- function(las) {
    res <- ForestTools::mcws(ttops, chm, minHeight, format = "raster")
    return(res)
  }
  
  f <- plugin_its(f)
  return(f)
}
```

Then

```r
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
las = readLAS(LASfile)
chm <- rasterize_canopy(las, 1, p2r(0.15), pkg = "raster")
vwf_fun <- function(x){x * 0.06 + 0.5}
WindowFilter <- vwf(CHM = chm, winFun = vwf_fun)
algo = mcwatershed(WindowFilter, chm, 2)
las <- segment_trees(las, algo)
plot(las, color = "treeID")
```